# bash run python while output file is not empty

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a program which sometimes writes empty outputs

```
$ cat ex.py 
import numpy as np
outf = open('out.dat', 'w')
if np.random.random() < 0.2: print >> outf, 'something'
```

I want to run `ex.py` until there is content in `out.dat`. Here is my best attempt so far. This is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ cat ex.sh 
while [ -s out.dat ]
do
   python ex.py
done
~/Documents/bigyawarticle $ . ex.sh 
~/Documents/bigyawarticle $ tail out.dat
```

**Edit**
Thanks I got the spacing issue.

Comment: Whitespace matters. `[` is a command (literally, the same command also usable with the name `test`), not a piece of syntax. Just like  you have to type `ls -l` (with the space between the command name and its first argument) instead of `ls-l`, you can't run `[-s`.

Comment: BTW, this is something http://shellcheck.net/ will catch for you automatically.

Comment: Ahh. Now that you've edited it -- note that the while loop only runs if the file is **non**empty. So if the file is already empty, your new code will never run at all. Maybe you wanted `while ! test -s out.dat`?

Comment: That did the trick